# What is the proper way to pass parameter from one mapping to another?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller

What I am writing is an application about shops. Let's say that I have a form with few fields. My product has:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ShopFormDto {
    private String name;

    private String addressName;
    private String addressStreet;
    private String addressCode;
    private String addressCity;
```

I allow user to add all fields and let's say none of them are optional and I don't want to handle this issue on my frontend (I use thymeleaf).

```
@GetMapping("/add")
    public String getCreationForm(Model model,
                                  @RequestParam(name = "error_message", required = false) String error_message,
                                  @RequestParam(name = "message", required = false) String message) {

        model.addAttribute("supplierForm", new ShopFormDto());

        if (error_message != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error_message", error_message);
        }
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "shop/supplierForm";
    }
```

What I do is I have to check all fields and give user proper error message. How should this be handled. What I do right now is:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(Model model, ShopFormDto dto) {
        boolean httpUrlAddress =
                dto.getUrl().matches("https://.*") ||
                        dto.getUrl().matches("http://.*");
        boolean wwwUrlAddress = dto.getUrl().matches("www[.].*");
        boolean emptyUrlAddress = dto.getUrl().isEmpty();

        model.addAttribute("error_message", "Unable to add shop");
        model.addAttribute("supplierForm", new ShopFormDto());
        model.addAttribute("supplierList", shopService.findAll());
        if (dto.getName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/shop/add?error_message=" + "Shop name is empty";
        }
        if (dto.getAddressCity().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/shop/add?error_message=" + "City address is empty";
        }
        if (dto.getAddressCode().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/shop/add?error_message=" + "Code address is empty";
        }
        if (dto.getAddressName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/shop/add?error_message=" + "Name address is empty";
        }
        if (dto.getAddressStreet().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/shop/add?error_message=" + "Street address is empty";
        }
        if (emptyUrlAddress || httpUrlAddress || wwwUrlAddress) {
            if (shopService.add(dto)) {
                if (!defaultApproved) {
                    return "redirect:/shop/list?message=" + "Newly added shop has to be approved by admin.";
                } else {
                    return "redirect:/shop/list?message=" + "Shop has been added.";
                }
            }
        } else {
            return "redirect:/shop/add?error_message=" + "Incorrect URL address. Started with http:// or https:// or www.";
        }
        return "shop/list";
    }
```

What should I do to make my code cleaner and easier to develop? I am considering solutions that also help me focus on translations (i18n). Right now as You can see - I only handle english.

I am looking for a better way to pass error message than adding them as request params to my url string. Is there any better way to do this?